# Clarification creating new data source connection to Postgres from (SSRS)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, reporting-services, datasource

I have followed the [steps stated as per this article](http://postgresblog.blogspot.sg/2010/10/postgres-odbc-linked-server-sql-server.html?showComment=1402009492423#c8535350803841472835).

Last step: Creating Connection to Postgres from (SSRS).

1. Create a New data Source
2. Name : Test
3. Data Source Type: ODBC
4. Connection String: Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=testserver;Port=5432;Database=Test;Schema=public;
5. Connect using: Credentials stored securily in report server, eneter user_name, password and Test Connection

I have right click and added a new data source to the SSRS project. However I am perplexed why it is showing as "Shared Data Source".
For the connection string, I replaced the server with `localhost` and database with `myPGdb` and tested out the connection with localhost credentials. It's working.

**My questions are,**

- As shown in the below screen, why can't DNS based connection be used for new data source?
- At step 6, why is `Microsoft OLEDB Provider for ODBC Drivers` used instead of `PostgresSQL OLE DB Provider` when creating a `Linked Server on SQL Server` to connect to postgres database?
- I am facing lots of issues to view the tables from postgres DB connection manager. IT keeps showing "LOADING" and then an error pop up. Further when creating connection manager for the data source "initial catelog" is disabled by default and thus not allowing any way to select a table...
- Same goes for SSRS, within query builder, the tables can't be viewed.

[image]

---

### EDIT

ODBC Data Providers
[image: ODBC Data Providers]

OLE DB Initial Catelogue missing
[image: OLE DB Initial Catelogue missing]

Comment: What options are you presented with when you select the Change... button?

Comment: @lrb screens are attached for your reference. I managed to get ODBC worked via `ADO.Net Data Flow` and ODBC connection manager. But OLE DB is handled by SQL Server in a yucky way although most of its Data Flow components are for OLE DB. The only way I could enabled `initial catelogue` is by OLE DB to work by trying out a *Trial* version of third party provider `PGNP Native PostgresSQL Provider`. Yet it didn't pull the data out of the source into the destination. Is there any other built in work around within SQL Server itself for handling OLE DB with data sources other than MS Office products?